# Getting 404 error on font and font not working on iphone

Tags: css, iphone, fonts

I am trying to add a font to my website and have added my CSS below. Whilst using chrome I get a 404 message on both the ttf and woff fonts. It does display the font in the browser. When i test using an iphone the font does not show. can anyone maybe advise where i am going wrong?

```
@font-face{
    font-family:exo;src:url("/public/fonts/Exo-Regular.eot");
    src:url("/public/fonts/Exo-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Regular.svg#Exo-Regular") format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:exo-bold;
    src:url("/public/fonts/Exo-Bold.eot");
    src:url("/public/fonts/Exo-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("/public/fonts/Exo-Bold.svg#Exo-Bold") format("svg")}
```

Comment: I don't know the structure of your directories, but keep in mind that inside `url()` there must be an URL and **not** a PATH

Comment: Thanks for this response it helped resolve this issue. The fonts where available at that url but because i wasn't using the full url it was looking for this path in the css directory 'css/public/fonts...'. As my fonts folder was in the same directory as my css folder this was resolved by changing it to url("../fonts/Exo-Regular.woff")